# How Can I override InAppBrowser's url?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am trying to override the InAppBrowser url using the on `loadstart` event but unfortunately with no luck, i don't know if i am missing something or even if this is applicable or not.

What i am trying to do is i am concatenating the url with a string so when the user clicks any url in the InAappBrowser window i override that url with the concatenated string.

I would appreciate any help, or if anybody had tried something like this before.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  browser: any;

  constructor(
    public iab: InAppBrowser
  ) {}

  openPage(){
    this.browser = this.iab.create('http://example.com','_blank','hidden=no,location=yes');
    this.browser.on('loadstart')
    .subscribe(
      data => data.url = data.url + '?mydata=true'
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to execute javascript code on loadstart to override any url clicked with my new url using the `executeScript` InAppBrowser method.

```
openPage(){
    this.browser = this.iab.create('https://example.com/','_blank','hidden=yes,location=yes,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
    this.browser.on('loadstart')
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        if(!data.url.includes('?mydata=true')){
          this.browser.executeScript({
            code: `window.location.href = '${data.url}' + '?mydata=true';`
          });
        } 
      }
    );
    this.browser.show(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying the location string to the one you want but are not loading it up. This needs to be loaded in the browser again:

```
data.url = data.url + '?mydata=true'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give an example?